# creating elements in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't understand how elements are created in React.

I have some code below where the goal is to create elements on a form submit using a value from a `refs` - so for every submit in a form, it creates a new `<h1>` tag with the content of the textbox inside of it. A sample of what I'm trying to do looks like:

```
...

addHeader(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newHeader = this.refs.post.value;
    var newpost = React.createElement("h1", {
      type: "text", 
      value: newHeader
    });
  }

...

render() {
    return (
      <div className="form-section">
          { newPost }
            <form onSubmit={this.addHeader.bind(this)}>
                <input id="input-post" type="text" placeholder="Post Here" ref="post" />
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
            <button className="form-section__submit" onClick={this.clearFields.bind(this)}>Clear All</button>      
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Basically my thinking is in my `addHeader()` function I'm assigning a variable of `newPost` to the method and calling it within my component. This code is causing 2 errors:

> 33:9 warning 'newpost' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
>
> 49:13  error 'newPost' is not defined  no-undef

What I don't understand, is (from what I can see) I am assigning a value to that variable and also using it in the component that I am rendering... along with that, I don't understand this error message. How can something be assigned a value but be undefined at the same time...? Is it because it's in the wrong scope? How do I declare where the new element is rendered specifically in the component?

[I read the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#createelement) but it doesn't give a clear answer as to how to control where in the component the new element is rendered.

Comment: Your variable is named `newpost` but you use `newPost` in `render()`. Note the lowercase vs. uppercase `p`.

Comment: It's also unaccessible because it's in another method's scope.

Comment: Also, if you already using jsx there is no need to use React.CreateElement.

Answer (score 0):

Made some changes to your code. You're going to want to initialize component state in your `constructor`. In your `addHeader` method you will use `this.setState` to update the state of the component with a new posts value including the value of `this.input`. I changed your `ref` on the input an actual ref. You take the element and store on `this`. Every time you add a new post you will get a new `<h1>` with the value of the `textarea`.

```
...

addHeader(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState((prevState, props) => {
        return { posts: [ ...prevState.posts, this.input.value ] };
    });
  }

...

render() {
    const { posts } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="form-section">
          { posts.map( text => <h1>{ text }</h1> ) }
            <form onSubmit={this.addHeader.bind(this)}>
                <input id="input-post" type="text" placeholder="Post Here" ref={ el => this.input = ref } />
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
            <button className="form-section__submit" onClick={this.clearFields.bind(this)}>Clear All</button>      
      </div>
    );
  }
```

**As an aside**: Binding functions in the `render` method of react components will cause a performance hit. There is no need to re-bind the this context of the function on every render. `this.clearFields.bind(this)` should become `this.clearFields` and you will need to add `this.clearFields = this.clearFields.bind(this)` to your `constructor`. You do not need to bind functions that are not used as callbacks.

You're going to want to do the same thing for `this.addHeader.bind(this)`.